# How to save results of Model to text file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to save the Frequent itemsets generated from the model to a text file. The code is an example of FPGrowth example in Spark ML library.

Using `saveAsTextFile` directly on the model writes the RDD locations and not the actual values.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val data = sc.textFile("/home/ponny/Freq")
val data1 = sc.textFile("/home/ponny/Scala_Examples/test.txt")
val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))
val tdata: RDD[Array[String]] = data1.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))

val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.0).setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { itemset =>
  println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}
model.freqItemsets.saveAsTextFile("/home/ponny/Freq_op")
```

The output generated in text file is like

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@5b27c9
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@2a7acd
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@d4d011
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@1fd4350
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same way how you print the values. Build desired output string first:

```
model.freqItemsets
  .map { fi => s"""[${fi.items.mkString(",")}], ${fi.freq}""" }
  .saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Comment: Is there different method to save the logistic regression output. I tried to print also using but unable to do.

Comment: @JayashreeRout `LogisticRegressionModel.save`

Comment: Thanks @Zero323 it is working. If I want to print then?