# How to save FP-Growth model FrequentItemSet results in to a text file?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to save the Frequent itemsets generated from the model to a text file. The code is an example of FPGrowth example in Spark ML library.
Using saveAsTextFile directly on the model writes the RDD locations and not the actual values.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowthModel;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test_ItemFrequency {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FP-Growth_ItemFrequency").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("/data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt");

        JavaRDD<List<String>> transactions = data.map(new Function<String, List<String>>() {
            public List<String> call(String line) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                return Arrays.asList(parts);
            }
        });

        FPGrowth fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.2).setNumPartitions(1);
        FPGrowthModel<String> model = fpg.run(transactions);

        model.freqItemsets().saveAsTextFile("/home/data/itemset");

        sc.stop();
    }
}
```

The output generated in text file is like

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@754881de
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@73022909
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@25df2591
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@774b6aca
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@100ba1db
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@72a388b2
org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth$FreqItemset@2e8cc8da
```

can anyone explain how to fix? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35969258/1560062

Comment: can you share java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using lambda expressions** :

```
model.freqItemsets()
     .toJavaRDD()
     .map((Function<FPGrowth.FreqItemset<String>, String>) fi -> fi.javaItems() + " -> " + fi.freq())
     .saveAsTextFile("/home/data/itemset");
```

We converted the `FPGrowth.FreqItemSet` into a `JavaRDD<String>` so we can save it afterwards.

Solution **without lambda expressions** :

```
model.freqItemsets()
     .toJavaRDD()
     .map(new Function<FPGrowth.FreqItemset<String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(FPGrowth.FreqItemset<String> fi) {
                return fi.javaItems() + " -> " + fi.freq();
            }
        }
     ).saveAsTextFile("/home/data/itemset");
```